# react TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

From "orders" component, sending a order id to "update" component. Then trying to update "the status" of the order containing the id.

Logging the id value in the console works, but not setting a state with it.

**"Update" component:**

```
const UpdateStatus = (props) => {
    const location = useLocation();
    const [orderId, setOrderId] = useState(null);
    const [status, setStatus] = useState("pending");

    useEffect(() => {
        setOrderId(location.state.id);  // errors here
        console.log(location.state.id)  // but gives a valid id
     }, [location]);

    const handleChange = e => {
        setStatus(e.target.value);
        console.log(e.target.value)
    }

    const history = useHistory();
    const handleClick = () => {
        if (orderId){
        axios.patch(`http://localhost:5000/orders/change-status/${orderId}`, {status: status}, {withCredentials: true})
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
                history.push("/get-orders");
            })
        }
    }

    return (  
        <div> 
            <h2> Update Order Status </h2>
            <form>
                <label>Change status to: </label>
                <select name="status" id="order-status" onChange={handleChange}>
                    <option value="pending">Pending</option>
                    <option value="accepted">Accepted</option>
                    <option value="delivered">Delivered</option>
                </select>
                <br/><br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick={handleClick}/>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**"Orders" component:**

```
const handleClick = orderId => {
        history.push({
            pathname: '/update-status',
            state: { id: orderId }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
useEffect(() => {
 if(location?.state?.id)
    setOrderId(location.state.id); 
 }, [location?.state?.id]);
```

Comment: thanks. could you explain a bit on why it gives this error when it can still be console logged?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
useEffect(() => {
        setOrderId(location.state?.id);  
       .......... 
 }, [location]);
```